# Stopwatch with PyGame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

**Hi everyone!** I want to create **a stopwatch** with pygame. I saw **this** code:

```
import pygame as pg

pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((400, 650))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
font = pg.font.Font(None, 54)
font_color = pg.Color('springgreen')

passed_time = 0
timer_started = False
done = False

while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                timer_started = not timer_started
                if timer_started:
                    start_time = pg.time.get_ticks()

    if timer_started:
        passed_time = pg.time.get_ticks() - start_time

    screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
    text = font.render(str(passed_time / 1000), True, font_color)
    screen.blit(text, (50, 50))

    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)

pg.quit()
```

but when you press the spacebar, the timer restarts. how can i print it (on the screen)?

Comment: This code is nice and works fine. The timer restarts when you press the space bar twice. What do you want to "print on the screen"?

Comment: I guess You want to save results and get printed them on screen. for that You will need to save result each time You stop the stopwatch

Answer (score 0):

here is the updated code (since I assumed that You want to print multiple results on the screen, that is what I did):

```
import pygame as pg

pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((400, 650))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
font = pg.font.Font(None, 54)
font_color = pg.Color('springgreen')

passed_time = 0
start_time = None
timer_started = False
done = False

results = []

while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                timer_started = not timer_started
                if timer_started:
                    start_time = pg.time.get_ticks()
                elif not timer_started:
                    results.append(passed_time)
                    if len(results) > 10:
                        results.pop(0)

    if timer_started:
        passed_time = pg.time.get_ticks() - start_time

    screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
    text = font.render(f'{(passed_time / 1000):.3f}', True, font_color)
    screen.blit(text, (50, 50))

    for index, result in enumerate(results):
        text = font.render(f'{(result / 1000):.3f}', True, font_color)
        screen.blit(text, (50, 50 + 54 * (len(results) - index)))

    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)

pg.quit()
```

The way this works: if the stopwatch is stopped the value it was stopped at gets appended to the list.

Then later in the code it reads each item in the list and puts it on the screen.

`(50, 50 + 54 * (len(results) - index))` this makes sure that time is displayed in chronological order by when the time was recorded.

Also there is this part:

```
if len(results) > 10:
    results.pop(0)
```

which makes sure that the list doesn't get overfilled.